# getting google plus profile information to be shown for every user logging into my site

Tags: google-api, google-plus

can this be done anyhow ? I want to show every user , his google profile info ,or at least , create a profile widget for him on his home page .

Also , is it be possible to get the number of profiles with the highest followers in google plus , periodically,so that I can showcase that in my website ?

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't have an official API for the Google Plus product yet. You can sign up for a list to get the info as soon as it's available here:

https://services.google.com/fb/forms/plusdevelopers/

There are several "unofficial" api libraries you can try to use, but they're not likely to work very well as google plus is in beta, and is likely to keep changing without supporting unofficial libraries

Comment: Thanks ... I have signed up for the official google plus api...also got an unofficial api from github.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for the top users part of the question.

There are several unofficial projects are existing that can get information out of google+

[Dotnet.GooglePlus](https://github.com/gyurisc/dotnet.googleplus) is my own that is written in .NET, but there are java and PHP implementations as well.

The other option is to try scrape a site like http://socialstatistics.com/ for top users.